# Can I access Pip configuration via Pip's API?

Tags: python, pip

Pip has a configuration which is typically in `~/.pip/pip.conf` on Linux, `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` on Windows, and possibly other locations on virtual environments.

I could write some code to locate Pip's config file and then parse it using an ini-file parser (included with Python), however it occurs to me that this code must already exist within Pip. Pip surely must have a mechanism to locate and parse it's own configuration file.

I'd like to be able to access that configuration via Pip's API. In particular I'm trying to get hold of the index URL that Pip is using (along with any credentials which may be embedding). That will allow my service to guarantee that it's going to hit the same repository that Pip used to install from.

Is there an easy way to access this information?

The objective here is to access Pip's configuration information without having to re-implement the code which searches for Pip's config file.

Comment: Since there's no public pip API, even if you dig this up from the bowels of pip, it doesn't 'guarantee' anything since you don't know if the code you'll be calling will be there at all.

Comment: Perhaps API is too strong a word. For a given version of Pip, can I get which config file it is using? I'd rather not rewrite this logic. I found pip.locations.site_config_files, but those aren't actually the config files pip is using!

Comment: Right but that's neither version robust nor does it seem to achieve the goal of "That will allow my service to guarantee that it's going to hit the same repository that Pip used to install from.". After all the config can change, that being somewhat the point of a config.

Comment: sadly, that seems to be the truth.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this, but this gets you somewhat directly to the user's config file. This won't work for site-configs.

```
import os
import pip.appdirs
import pip.locations
os.path.join(pip.appdirs.user_config_dir("pip"), pip.locations.config_basename)
```

And a way that gets all the config file locations:

```
>>> from pip.baseparser import ConfigOptionParser
>>> ConfigOptionParser(name="foo").get_config_files()
['C:\\ProgramData\\pip\\pip.ini', 'C:\\Users\\salimfadhley\\pip\\pip.ini', 'C:\\Users\\salimfadhley\\AppData\\Roaming\\pip\\pip.ini']
>>>
```